# Html Encode on a string with symbols

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, symbols

How do I encode a string with symbols like ', & @ #' in ASP.Net MVC?

I have tried to use Html.Encode, but it returns '&#39', how do I return a string as the user input?

Thanks alot.

Comment: For some reason, it is not returning "&#39" on my question

Comment: What do you mean by "as the user input"? Can you show this part of the view?

Comment: For example, if a user input ', I will get ', now I am getting &#39; instead of '

Answer (score 4):

If you intend to insert the string into the HTML markup then you need to HTML encode it:

```
<%= Html.Encode("',&@#'") %>
```

or if you are using ASP.NET 4.0:

```
<%: "',&@#'" %>
```

Doing this will properly encode any characters in the string.

Comment: I have tried that, but it returns the code instead of the character.

Comment: Precisely, isn't what you were looking for?